# Passing undeclared props to child component (like ...args)

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I am making a wrapper component for a Vue component.

For example, I want to wrap Quasar's `q-input` (let's say because I am doing some custom styling:

```
// q-input-wrapper.vue
<template>
  <q-input v-model="inputValue" label="Some Label">
</template>
```

But then I want `q-input-wrapper` to be able to accept all props that `q-input` supports. I do not want to re-declare all of them in `q-input-wrapper.vue`.

Is there a way to bind props that are passed in `q-input-wrapper` for `q-input` to consume?

Example:

```
<q-input-wrapper color="blue" icon="mail" class="some-class" style="some-style: value" />
```

`color`, `icon` are both `q-input` props and I do not want to explicitly declare them as `q-input-wrapper`'s props but still want to use them.

Probably something similar to how `...args` work?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass along any props with `v-bind="$attrs"` and any listeners with `v-on="$listeners"`:

```html
<template>
  <q-input v-model="inputValue" label="Some Label"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wrapping-a-component-q31y5?file=/src/components/MyInput.vue)